# Constructing pandas dataframe with rows conditional on their not existing in another dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a pandas dataframe

```
df
store    day   items
 a        1     4
 a        1     3
 a        2     1
 a        3     5
 a        4     2 
 a        5     9
 b        1     1 
 b        2     3
```

I have another pandas dataframe `temp`
  that is the kronecker product of all unique store-day combinations, that is, it looks like:

```
    store  day  
0     a    1     
1     a    2      
2     a    3      
3     a    4      
4     a    5      
5     b    1      
6     b    2      
7     b    3    
8     b    4    
9     b    5
```

I want to make a new DF that is the missing observations in `df`, that is, the `store-day` combinations not present in `df`  but present in `temp`.

```
desired output


store    day
b         3      
b         4       
b         5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way

```
gcols = ['store', 'date']
tmp[tmp.set_index(gcols).index.isin(df.set_index(gcols).index) == False]
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution merges the two dataframes and uses `items` as a marker column - it will be `nan` for the rows we want. I believe that for large dataframes this would be more efficient than the alternative using `isin`. Had `items` not be there, I would've added a marker column to `df`.

So first the merge. It's important to specify `how = 'left'` so we'd get the rows from `tmp` that are not on `df`:

```
out = tmp.merge(df, on= ['store', 'day'], how = 'left')

In [23]: out
Out[23]: 
   store  day  items
0      a    1      4
1      a    1      3
2      a    2      1
3      a    3      5
4      a    4      2
5      a    5      9
6      b    1      1
7      b    2      3
8      b    3    NaN
9      b    4    NaN
10     b    5    NaN
```

You see that the rows we want received `nan` for their `items` column, since they were merged only from `tmp`. Now let's drop them, and get rid of the marker column.

```
out[out['items'].isnull()].drop(['items'], axis = 1)

   store  day
8      b    3
9      b    4
10     b    5
```

Answer (score 0):

newDF = pd.merge(df,temp,how='right',on=['store','day'])

newDF[newDF.isnull().any(axis=1)]